# Create tile pyramid from large amount of GeoTIFFs

Tags: geotiff-tiff, gdal2tiles

I have a large set of GeoTIFFs, about 12 000 files (total 18GB), that together forms one large map. What would be the best approach to create a tile pyramid out of this dataset?

I'm thinking that to join the GeoTIFFss to one large file and then create a image pyramid would be one way, although I think that it might be that the size of the combined file could be to large to handle?

Is there any other way that might be better/quicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with 18Gb is not that big (and I expect it could be smaller with [compression](https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html)) but the easy way to do this is to make a virtual dataset using [`gdalbuildvrt`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html) and then tile that file using [`gdal2tiles.py`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html)